# Hive copy from partitioned table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, partitioning

I have an original table that is partitioned on YEAR, MONTH and DATE. For example:

```
col_1    col_2    col_3    YEAR    MONTH    DATE 
a        b        c        2017    03       25
```

I want to create a new table which is a subset of this table, but still maintains the partitioning of the original table.

Something as simple as

```
CREATE new_table AS 
SELECT * 
FROM original_table 
WHERE (conditions);
```

However, because the original table is so big, I have to iterate through this query via the partitions.

My current solution is to write a shell script that iterates through all partitions and runs a separate query for each partition.

Example:

```
for year in '2016' '2017'
    do
    for month in '01' '02' ...
        do
        for day in '01' '02' ...
            do
            hive -e "INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM original_table WHERE YEAR=$year AND MONTH=$month etc."
        done
    done
done
```

But this appears very round-about and inefficient. Is there a way to do this as one line directly in hive?

Comment: Are these external or internal tables?

Comment: You're not inserting into any partitions... Did you try `WHERE year BETWEEN '2016' AND '2017'`, for example within the query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recently had to do something like this for a subset of days, but it requires you to copy the schema of the original table, or at least use `CREATE TABLE LIKE`

But, most importantly, you're insert statement needs to specify the partitions

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (
    fields... 
)
PARTITIONED BY (year STRING, month STRING, day  STRING);

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE new_table PARTITION(year, month, day) 
SELECT fields... , year, month, day -- partitions must be last
FROM original_table
WHERE 
year BETWEEN '2016' AND '2017';  -- add more, as necessary
```

You might also be able to use a CTAS function, but doing those with partitioned tables isn't straightforward